# Adding a cusotm title for javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript, popup

I have a code snippet inside my team site home page which contain the following code to display a pop-up dialog, as follow:-

```
<li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(&#39;http://192.168.8.150/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=7432&#39;,null,800,775);" unselectable="on"> Live</a></li>
```

But currently the pop-up will have the text "Dialog" at the top of it, my question is if there is there a way to define a custom title for this pop-up. currently the pop-up will be displayed as follow:-

[image]

**::Edit::**
i tried adding the following to my original code snippet :-

```
var options = {
        url: "http://192.168.8.221/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=726",
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        title: "Hi World"
    };


  <li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);" unselectable="on">Camera One</a></li>
```

But the code snippet did not recognize the word `var options ={...` so will it be possible to add such a code in a code snippet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a title, I think you'd want to use the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);` format. You can create an options object to pass into the call, giving you the ability to set height, width, and title.

```
    var options = {
        url: "http://192.168.8.150/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=7432",
        width: 650,
        height: 300,
        title: "Hi World"
    };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can you check my Edit .

Comment: ok i added the options inside a Script tag.